# Newbie: How to add descriptive text to formset on a per-field basis?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using model-based forms, and I want to have more descriptive text for fields in addition to the label.  I've created a dictionary keyed on the field name, but I can't figure out how to get Django to render it in the template.

My form looks like this:

```
class GameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['event_name',
                  'game_system',
                  'duration_in_minutes',
                  'player_max',
                  'short_description',
                  'long_description',
                  ]
    field_text = dict(
            game_system='Traveller, D&D 4th Edition, etc',
            duration_in_minutes='30 - 600 minutes',
            player_max='Include yourself if you will be playing',
            short_description='For program book and signup sheets',
            long_description='For website',
            )
```

I've tried various ways of accessing the dictionary in the template, nothing works. the most intuitive to me would be {{ field_text.field.name }} but that comes up empty. I can display the entire dictionary, but i can't index into it.

I've looked through the various Forms pages in the Django docs, but if this is addressed there I've missed it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `help_text` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#help-text)) in your model. Here's an example:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    game_system = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Traveller, D&D 4th Edition, etc')
    duration_in_minutes = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, help_text='30 - 600 Minutes')
```

Now you can access this information in your template with `{{ field.help_text }}`.